# Appcelerator WebView can´t load URL

Tags: android, webview, titanium, appcelerator

i´am test an url (http://docker.itop.es:10101) and the WebView don´t load.

My Code:

```
var web = Titanium.UI.createWebView();

web.height = "100%";
web.width = "100%";
web.ignoreSslError = true;
web.scalesPageToFit = false;
web.enableZoomControls = false;
web.showScrollbars = false;
web.scrollsToTop = false;
web.pluginState = Titanium.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_PLUGINS_ON;
web.url = "http://docker.itop.es:10101/";

$.index.add(web);
$.index.open();
```

I tested Titanium SDK 6.1.1 6.1.2 and 5.1.1

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried putting all the fields inside the `createWebview` method? `createWebview({height: '',url: ''});` etc..

Comment: yes, but fails too

Comment: Have you tried another URL? It looks like your URL requires authentication?

Comment: Does this work with older version of the SDK? Also when you say it does not load, does it mean, that the blue background login page is not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my webview did not load.

Ultimately the solution for me was urlencoding the json stringified data I was sending to it. This is not the solution to this particular issue, however it might help other visitors finding this question like I did.